# office.js open taskpane programmatically

Tags: office-js, excel-addins

I know we can provide a button in the ribbon and set the action as `ShowTaskpane`. Then the taskpane will open on click of the button.
We want to open a taskpane when a cell with formula is selected just like `Pivot Table Fields` taskpane will appear if you selected a cell within the pivot table.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add-ins cannot be launched conditionally based on the context of selected data. The nearest you could get would be to [automatically open a task pane with a document](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/design/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document).

I recommend visiting the [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and adding your suggestion.